# How can i check a Long data type number a power of 2 or not using a&(a-1)==0 in JAVA

Tags: java, operators

here is what i tried. it says second operand is boolean whereas first is long. so & operator is undefined for long and boolean .

```
public static void powerOfTwo(long a){
   if(a & (a-1) == 0 )
      System.out.println("it's a power of two");
   else
      System.out.println("NOT a power of two");
}
```

Comment: Note: `0` is not a power of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap the expression in extra parenthesis:

```
public static void powerOfTwo(long a) {
    if ((a & (a - 1)) == 0)
        System.out.println("it's a power of two");
    else
        System.out.println("NOT a power of two");
}
```

That's because the operator `==` takes precedence over `&` (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)), so without the braces, you have

```
a & (a - 1) == 0
```

which is the same as

```
a & ((a - 1) == 0)
```

and then the compiler complains about comparing a long (`a`) with a boolean `(a-1 == 0)`

Comment: huh? `==` has a higher associativity than `&` ?! Java never ceases to amaze me with bad choices, if this is true.

Comment: It's true. Shudder. Java, I hate you.

Comment: Yeah, I was also surprised :)

Comment: So bonkers. No sane language should do that. It's just so natural to assume that the comparison operators all are below the bit-wise operators in precedence. NOPE. Java, you buggy hell of a language: `a << 1 == 4` works as expected, whereas `a & 1 == 1` will not.

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ I agree that it would be more natural if `&` had higher precedence than `==`, but this is not a Java "bug", it comes from C/C++. So you probability should have complained with Dennis Ritchie. Unfortunately it's too late for that.

Comment: @HelderPereira: agreed, and it's definitely nothing I like about C. (C++ needed to adapt it because it originally was designed with compatibility in mind). But taking that and putting it into your new language? Insane. It was a design mistake of the 1970s and should have died eons ago.

Comment: BTW Some don't consider `0` to be a power of two.

Comment: perfect !! . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
return a != 0 && ((a & (a-1)) == 0);
```

however this is obscure. A simpler way is

```
return Long.bitCount(a) == 1
```

This is not entirely obvious either but having exactly one bit set means it must be a power of 2.